# Ancestor lookup in service cloud console

Tags: formula, service-cloud-console

My Case has a lookup-field for Contact, which in turn has a lookup-field for a custom object Customer. How can I directly open the Customer record in a subtab from the Case detail page?

So I'd like to have a field on the standard Case page layout which shows the Customer name, and when you click on it the customer record opens in a subtab.

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you could do this would be by using a custom link on your cases page.

1. Go to Customize->Cases->Buttons, Links, Actions
2. Create a New Button/Link.
3. Behavior : **Display in a new Window**
4. URL: **"/{!Contact.CustomerId__c}"** (You might have to replace the exact name based on your object name)
5. Save

Then go to the page layout of the Case Object and add this new button/link there.

Comment: Wow that worked! I used another behavior (display in same window with side bar). Can you explain why the url is for Contact.CustomerId__c? I tried Contact.Customer__c but that didn't work..

Comment: When you use just Customer__c that refers to the Name or whatever is the default parameter for Customer.
But to access a record from the URL you need the unique 15-char record id associated with that customer record.

Comment: Another question: Using the Link the scenario works like a charm. When I use a button (with the same settings) it is opened over the current tab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a junction object. In this case you'd need to make the Contact your junction object.

The junction object would have master-detail relationships with the 2 objects you want to connect ( in this case "Case" and "Customer")

Case **--master detail relationship -->** Contact **<-- master detail relationship --** Customer

This would then allow you to access the customer records from the case object.

I hope this answers your question. I'm unable to see the image you've posted for some reason.

If you'd like a more detailed, step-by-step solution take a look at the Relationships chapter in Force.com fundamentals

Comment: The Case & Contact objects are standard SF objects, and the lookup for a Contact on the Case page is a standard Field. I cannot (and don't want to) change this lookup into a master detail relationship.. Can you please answer the question given that the data model is fixed?